# How to append success=true on django tastypie json

Tags: python, django, extjs, tastypie

I am using django-tastypie to implement restapi, i am using sencha as a mobile client . I need to manipulate the response text for some purpose.

Like below

```
form.submit({
    success: function() {
        // The callback function is run when the user taps the 'ok' button
        form.reset();

        //Ext.Msg.alert('Thank You', 'Your message has been received', function() {
        //  form.reset();
        //});
    }
});
```

I have json response as follows

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 13},       
 "objects": [{"body": "This will prbbly be my lst edited  post.", "id": 1,
 "pub_date":  "2011-05-22", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/entry/1/", "slug": "another-post", 
 "title": "Another Post"}, {"body": "This will prbbly be my lst post.", "id": 2, 
 "pub_date": "2011-05-22", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/entry/2/", "slug": "another-post", 
 "title": "Another Post"}, {"body": "This will prbbly be my lst edited  post"}]}
```

It is very important to send success => true
If, success is not defined or not equal to true then it will be considered as a form submit error.
How to append success=true on django tastypie json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to append `{'success': true}` to the result of API calls, correct? If so, you can override the [dehydrate](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#dehydrate) method on your `Resource` class:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['success'] = True
    return bundle
```

Comment: Wont' that do it for all request types, as in `GET` ?